# ERROR ! ERROR !Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

If I make a minimum api of 14 in unity 3d, apk becomes. But when I do 9 I get the following error. I tried everything on the ethernet but it is not. Can you help me ?

```
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\aksel\Desktop\Unity3Ddenemeleri\New Unity Project 2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'

Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\aksel\Desktop\Unity3Ddenemeleri\New Unity Project 2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:7] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'

CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/aksel/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\aksel\Desktop\Unity3Ddenemeleri\New Unity Project 2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\aksel\Desktop\Unity3Ddenemeleri\New Unity Project 2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:7] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\aksel\Desktop\Unity3Ddenemeleri\New Unity Project 2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\aksel\Desktop\Unity3Ddenemeleri\New Unity Project 2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\aksel\Desktop\Unity3Ddenemeleri\New Unity Project 2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gass-10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\aksel\Desktop\Unity3Ddenemeleri\New Unity Project 2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-10.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: Are you using plugins? If so, name them and their versions. That's likely the problem

Comment: It is probably caused by a library that you added to your project (`Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'`) as pointed [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1217594/unable-to-merge-android-manifests-3.html).